# Presenting a View Controller with an xib from an SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I have tried many things, none of which are working. I have an *SKScene*, and when the game is over, I want it to go back to the original view controller. Thank you in advance.

I have tried this in my SKScene

```
homeScreenViewController *viewCont = [[homeScreenViewController alloc] init];
            [viewCont viewDidLoad];
```

This in my other view controller

```
constructinoViewController *view = [[constructinoViewController alloc ] init];
        [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It mostly says **The view is not in the view hierarchy**.

Comment: show us the code you have tried and define what is not working...

Comment: What is your ViewController hierarchy like? How is your SpriteKit scene presented?

Comment: What do you mean by that? It is presented in the original view controller

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to send the parent viewController a message.

In your viewController which presents the SKScene, add the following line in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closeScene) name:@"closeScene" object:Nil];
```

Also, add this method

```
-(void)closeScene
{
    //Remove the SKView, or present another viewController here.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"closeScene" object:nil];
}
```

Then in your SKScene, at the point where your game ends,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"closeScene" object:nil];
```

You can do this by using delegates as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The only problem is that it still does not go back to the view controller. The closeScene method IS being called. Do i need to do something  else in addition?

Comment: Ok, please attach two more parts of code to the question. 1- which is used to present the skscene. 2- the class names of the viewController in which you are presenting the SKScene and the one which you want to present from the scene

Comment: Ok, The scene is presented from "levelOneViewController", and it is presented like SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = NO;
    skView.showsNodeCount = NO;
    
    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [level1 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    
    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];

Comment: The classs i want to presnet from the skscene is homeViewController

Comment: You need to put in more code in the closeScene method which will actually present the new viewController. I left that part with a comment so you could post some code in there as well.

Comment: Also, you are initializing the viewController incorrectly if you are using an XIB. it should be: homeScreenViewController *viewCont = [[homeScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"homeScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
            [viewCont viewDidLoad];

Comment: It is with a story board

Answer (score 0):

If you have presented the ViewController, then you need to dismiss it to return to previous ViewController.

You should use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, where would I put this? I cannot put it in an SKScene

Comment: You need to send a notification to your view controller which added your SKScene to its view. Consider ViewController1 presented ViewController2 and in ViewController2's view, you added your game scene. Once the game is over, fire a notification to ViewController2 and in the notification function, write the above code.